# HTML & CSS: Using CSS to properly align <h1> and <p> tags

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have a problem regarding "div" tags - both with text and headings.
Since I cannot yet upload pictures (due to me being a noob on here) I will try to explain to the best of my ability.

- One "div" has got a "h1" followed by a "p". The whole "div" is floated left.
- The other "div" has got a "h2" follow by a "p". The whole "div" is floated right.

Since the two "text-divs" are next to each other, I want the "p" in both of them to align and mirror perfectly. Since my "h1" is bigger than my "h2", the "p" in the first "div" is pushed further down than the "p" in the other side.

Is there a clever way to solve this problem? I have tried playing with the margin and padding, but it seems to be complicated to get it to fit!

Hope you understand,

Best CSS_maniac

Comment: perhaps you could set up a jsfiddle to reproduce the problem, much better then an image and then we have something concrete to work from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are at least 10 ways to solve this problem.

you could add any of the following attributes to either of the p tags

`position: relative; top: (specify amount in px or em, without parentheses);`

`margin-top: 10px;`

`position: absolute; // Very similar to position: relative;`

good Luck

-Brian

Comment: I think I like your suggestion to use `position: absolute` on the `p` tags better than my solution, @bwheeler96.  It's a better guarantee that they'll align properly regardless of the `h1` and `h2` rules. OP, just remember to set `position: relative` on the containing div so that the `p`s aren't aligning absolute *to the page*.  You'll also have to set a height on the containing divs.

Comment: So the position: relative; top: "amount" is the distance to the heading?

Comment: If you're talking about setting `position: relative; top: <amount>;` on the `p` elements, it's the `top` position relative to where the `p` would normally lie.  If the `p` was normally displaying directly below the heading, setting `top: 5px` would make it lie 5px lower than it would otherwise be.

Comment: Thank you. I just wondered - how do I know when the two p tags are at the exact same height? (without eyeballing it)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd suggest using a CSS reset script to limit the number of variables (margin, padding, text size) you're playing with and to make sure this renders properly in all browsers.  [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is really popular.  Then you can adjust `font-size` on the h1 and h2 to get them displaying as you like, and adjust the `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` on the h1 and h2 to make the p's align properly.